# Не работает программа в IDLE Python

Tags: python

Изучаю Python по учебнику. Не работает программа. При запуске в IDLE >>>[image: Скриншот работы программы]

```py
def function(foo):
    print(foo)
#Начало программы
class Critter:(object):
"""Виртуальный питомец"""
def talk(self):
print("Привет. Я зверюшка - экземпляр класса Critter.")
#основная часть
crit = Critter()
crit.talk()
input("\n\nНажмите Enter,чтобы выйти.")
```

Comment: Внесите исправления в свой первый вопрос. Не следует плодить одно и то же.

Comment: Я просто не знаю как править. Я уже скачал пайчарм там все работает. Не понятно только почему в python IDLE не работает.

Comment: "Я просто не знаю как править." - ссылка "править" под вопросом для кого?

Answer (score 0):

```js
#Вариант 1: (следите за отступами и синтаксисом)
class Critter(object):
    """ Виртуальный питомец """
    def talk(self) :
        print("Привет. Я зверюшка - экземпляр класса Critter.")
# основная часть
crit = Critter()
crit.talk()
input("\n\nHaжмитe Enter, чтобы выйти.")
      
# Вариант 2 (для Python 3)
class Critter(): 
      """ Виртуальный питомец """
      def talk():
          print("Привет. Я зверюшка - экземпляр класса Critter.")
# основная часть
Critter.talk()
input("\nНажмите Enter, чтобы выйти.")
```

Comment: В Python3 никто не запрещает наследоваться от object (хотя это и не обязательно). Проблема в отступах и синтаксисе (двоеточие перед `(object)`, например).